# Caught between "Line is longer than 80 characters" and "File contains tab characters"

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have installed the latest version of Checkstyle in my Eclipse.
The problem is this: If I set the Tab policy to "Tabs" I get all the "File contains tab characters" errors. If I set the Tab policy in Formatter to "Spaces only" I get rid of the "File contains tab characters" checkstyle errors BUT I get lots of "Line is longer than 80 characters errors", even when they make no sense, in my opinion. For example:

```
FulltimeEmployee a = new FulltimeEmployee(
                         parsedLine[READ_LINE_FIRST_PARAMETER],     
                         parsedLine[READ_LINE_SECOND_PARAMETER],
                         Integer.decode(parsedLine[2].trim()));
```

Now, all those line have actually about 40 "useful" characters. The rest come from indentation. I don't see how I could further break down those lines to conform to the 80 rule. Should I set Indentation size to less than 4 spaces? 
I thought about simplifying my code to not be so deeply indented, but I don't see how. See below for more code listing, perhaps you can suggest how I can reduce indentation. Even if that is the case here, my original problem still stands. The first indentation in front of the method is from the class.

```
public void populateList() {
     String[] parsedLine = new String[NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS];
     try {
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(Company.fileName);
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String readLine;
          while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
               parsedLine = readLine.split(", ");
               if (parsedLine.length != NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS) {
                    System.out.println("Format error");
               } else {
                    switch (parsedLine[READ_LINE_THIRD_PARAMETER]) {
                    case "full-time":
                         FulltimeEmployee a = new FulltimeEmployee(
                              parsedLine[READ_LINE_FIRST_PARAMETER],
                              parsedLine[READ_LINE_SECOND_PARAMETER],
                              Integer.decode(parsedLine[2].trim()));
                         this.employeeList.add(a);
//more code here
```

Any suggestions? I have thought long about this and searched quite a bit, but am at a loss.

Comment: But the main point of line length is in terms of the right margin. Imagine what would happen if you printed your code.

Comment: I see the point of the 80 limitation, I can't see what I can do to conform with it. :)

Comment: In my opinion, 80 is too narrow. I use 100-120. What you can do is refactor to avoid deep nesting, or reduce the indentation step to 3 or even 2.

Comment: Marko is right, 80 is rediculous for source code.

Comment: *If* you have a right margin at all, 80 (or even a bit less) is a safe choice. If that's too narrow for you, and you don't intend to view your code on anything where the right margin would cause an issue, just disable the warning altogether. The only way moving the right margin to 120 would be useful is if you actually have and use a screen/window/printer with 120 columns; if you don't, there's no reason to take that route.

Comment: @hvd Don't you just hate it when you see source code with lines occasionally 500+ characters long? Such code is a terrible nightmare to me. On the other hand, today's widescreen monitors easily accomodate at least 120 chars per line. More than that and it is hard for the eye to track to the next line from the end of a long line, even though the display would handle it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That would count as "if you actually have and use a window with 120 columns". I usually don't, because I have better uses for the remainder of the screen.

Comment: @Michael-O But check [this historical document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#262) :)

Comment: @hvd I checked it: my 120-char editor occupies exactly half the screen width. When I code, there's really nothing important besides code itself and a navigation bar (Package Explorer or whatever) to the side. In fact, everything else is a debilitating distraction.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, thanks it's 1999. I would consider it outdated.

Comment: @Michael-O If you browse around, you'll see just [**how much you're right**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#2991)! (See 6.3, Placement)

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help, I got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

use limitation - 120 symbols in line. Checkstyle should help your team to work in more uniform way, but to make you suffer, adjust it to your needs! 
Now we have wide screens and this rule become outdated.

To make Line length be even more relaxed you can try our [extension](http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.com/sevntu.checkstyle/) to checkstyle, search LineLengthExtendedCheck.